# Google assistant account linking with facebook

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, actions-on-google

I'm trying to make a chatbot with Dialogflow for Google Home. It requires the user to input a URL. Now it will definitely be a long and complicated URL which I can't recreate and I can't have the user speak into the google home.

The idea I had was that the user would input the URL on an agent on messenger. I store this on a Firebase database and then access it with a second agent.

Now the issue I have is authentication, I was hoping to use account linking on my google action with facebook. But I can't login to Facebook with google home. Or if I can, I can't find any documentation specific to that case. Facebook doesn't provide the necessary client ID and secret(as far as I can see).

I managed amazon and Gmail account linking with Alexa and an Amazon Echo. In those cases, you would have to login to google or amazon on the Alexa app or webpage. Then this will be integrated with your Echo and the skill will become usable.

Anyone have an idea of how I can make the link happen, if not then anyone have an idea as to how I can solve the overall problem?

This question has been left unanswered on other forums, but I was hoping to either get it solved or find an alternative.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, resp.what your specific problem is. How account linking works, which steps have to be performed - explained in the documentation. Whether Google Assistant allows you to implement those steps as necessary - dunno, that’s for you to figure out.

Comment: I'll edit the question, that would work better than commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three approaches to solving your overall problem - getting the URL manually entered and available to your Action. Two of them tackle it the way you've suggested - involving authenticating to Facebook and tying that to the Assistant account somehow. One solves it entirely inside the Assistant.

**Account linking to the Facebook account**

You've tagged firebase-authentication, so I'm going to assume that you're using it to do the auth and you've enabled Facebook login through it. This means your user has a "Firebase Account", but they log into that account using Facebook.

I will assume you have a way to get the URL from messenger once they're logged in.

The trick in this case is to setup [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) between their Firebase account and their Assistant account. This is done by setting up an [OAuth2 server](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow) that has access to the Firebase accounts and will create authorization and refresh tokens that are given to the Assistant.

In the Action, you'll send the user to the [Sign In helper](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#account_sign-in), which will redirect them to your login page and send back a one-time auth code to the Assistant. The assistant will then use your OAuth2 server to exchange this code for auth and refresh tokens. Periodically it will use the refresh token to get new auth tokens.

When the user returns to the conversation through the Assistant, you'll be handed an auth token and you can use this to lookup the user. Since you also know their Facebook account, you can get the URL via however you planned to do so.

There are drawbacks to this method - it is very complicated, and setting up your own OAuth2 server is not for the faint of heart. You may be able to use something like [Auth0](http://auth0.com/) instead of Firebase Authentication to accomplish the same thing, but then you don't have the ease of access to the Firebase database.

**Account linking to both Facebook and Google**

In your Firebase account, however, you don't need to limit them to just logging into Facebook. You can have them use Firebase to record *both* the Facebook and Google accounts that they're using. This would "link" the two accounts together in your system.

With this, you don't need to setup an OAuth2 server. Instead, you can have the Assistant use [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) for authentication. If the Google Cloud Project that Firebase is using and the Assistant are using are the same project, then once the user has logged in to your project's web page with their Google account, you'll get an identity token on the Assistant which will contain their Google ID. You can use this to match up with their Firebase account and get the Facebook ID and proceed from there.

But this is still a lot of work and kinda messy, jumping between systems.

**Using just the Google Assistant (and maybe a web page)**

If you're willing to make some assumptions about the devices your users are using, then you may be able to do it all *just* using the Assistant. The Assistant doesn't just run on the Google Home and other smart speakers, it also works on most current Android and iOS devices.

So you can [detect if they have such a device available](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations) and, if they do and they're not currently on it, [direct them to switch to that device](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations) when you need the URL.

If they don't have such a device available (perhaps because their version of Android is older), and you think this may be a common scenario, you may need to make another entry source available. This could be one of the solutions above, or you may want to just have a simple web page (done via Firebase Hosting and Firebase Functions, perhaps) where they log in using their Google account (so you get their ID) and you let them enter the URL. If you just need a URL - going through Dialogflow may be more complexity than you need.

Comment: This answer is pretty much perfect for what I was looking for. Turns out I didn’t need a Facebook login or a google login. I ended up setting up an amazon sign in that the user could use. It turns out that’s really easy to setup straight from the action/skill with just account linking. But honestly, this answer helps regardless